# Get the location of executables of nodes

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What should I do if I want to find the path to the executable for the node `spawner`  in the package `controller_manager` ?

```
bryant@bryant:~$ roscd controller_manager        
bryant@bryant:/opt/ros/kinetic/share/controller_manager$ ls
cmake  package.xml
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/306373/get-the-location-of-executables-of-nodes/) by [anonymous38087](https://answers.ros.org/users/38087/anonymous38087/) on ROS Answers with karma: 9 on 2018-10-21

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2018-10-21**:
You may want to look at how rosrun finds executables. Be warned, it's a bit of a mess to keep compatibility with rosbuild packages: https://github.com/ros/ros/blob/kinetic-devel/tools/rosbash/scripts/rosrun#L71

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-10-22**:
And just to avoid an [xy-problem](http://xyproblem.info): what is it that you're actually trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Please see #q209051.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-10-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [anonymous38087](https://answers.ros.org/users/38087/anonymous38087/) on 2018-11-02**:
Thank you.